# dojo enhanced grid server side pagination not working

Tags: datagrid, pagination, dojo

I'm facing an issue when trying to perform server side pagination using an enhanced datagrid (dojo v1.10).
The first page is correctly displayed, but the widget (store ? grid ? plugin ?) seems to ignore the 'Content-Range' header value in response and does not allow to get next page.
For example with response header containing 'Content-Range: items 0-9/17', pagination displays '1 to 10 of 10 items', and next page is not available.

After some debug I see that range value is correctly read from JsonRest store (query function)

```
    results.total = results.then(function(){
    var range = results.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
    return range && (range = range.match(/\/(.*)/)) && +range[1];
    }); 
...
```

But in fetch method from ObjectStore, totalCount value is undefined, results.length is then used:

```
var results = this.objectStore.query(query, args);
        Deferred.when(results.total, function(totalCount){
            Deferred.when(results, function(results){
                if(args.onBegin){
                    args.onBegin.call(scope, totalCount || results.length, args);
...
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,

My code:

```
// get grid store
var restStore = new JsonRest(
    {
        target: "ks2/api/workflow/...",
    });
var memoryStore = new Memory();
var store = Cache(restStore, memoryStore);      

/*set up layout*/
var layout = [{
            name: "id",
            field: 'id',
            width: '5%',
            datatype:"string"
        },
        ....
    ];

/*create a new grid*/
this.workflowGridWidget = new EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'workflowGridWidget',
        store: new ObjectStore({objectStore: store}),
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        plugins: {
            pagination: {
                          pageSizes: ["10", "25", "50"],
                          defaultPageSize: 10,
                          description: true,
                          sizeSwitch: true,
                          pageStepper: true,
                          gotoButton: true,
                          maxPageStep: 4,//page step to be displayed
                          position: "bottom" //position of the pagination bar
                      }
        }
    });

/*append the new grid to the div*/
this.workflowGridWidget.placeAt("workflowDataGrid");

/*Call startup() to render the grid*/
this.workflowGridWidget.startup();
```

Comment: Try to change the value of defaultPageSize to a bigger number, also you should try to remove it at all, sorry but I dont remember it so well but I had an issue related to that some years ago

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but no effect (defaultPageSize removed or with high value)

Comment: Have you tried using an Observable store instead of Cache and Memory? Something like... Store = `Observable( new JsonRestStore({}));`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I was using a non dojo restful compliant API, and I needed to add JSON response post-processing using

```
aspect.after(store, "query", this.processResponse);
...

processResponse: function ks2ProcessMonitor_datagrid_WorkflowDataGrid_processResponse(deferred) {
    return deferred.then(function(response) {
        //process response content
        return processedResponse;   
    });
},
```

This was working properly but for some reason, it has an impact on pagination. Removing this post-processing (using another API which is dojo compliant) fix the pagination issue.
Maybe I should try response post-processing using an Observable as suggested by Layke.